# split in Blocks data and obtain max/min in R

Tags: r, split, time-series

Currently I have a time-series with y-values = number of items and x-values = dates +time of purchase (ex. at 01/01/2020 13:45 someone bought 5 items). My data looks like the following image plus some noise (but lets imagine that it looks like a square signal):

[image]

However the width of each rectangle may vary. What I want to do is to obtain the min and max values in the x-axis when there are purchases present (ex. in the figure there might be purchases present in between the values 0.2 and 0.4, so those 2 values would be my min and max, respectively, but in my case would be date/time). However in this case there will be multiple blocks with varying length and I would like to extract only the min/max of that block, but it doesn't occur to my a way to do it since I am new in R. Does anyone could lead me to a possible way to solve this?

a very simplified example would be the following :

```
purchase.dates <- c("01/01/2020 20:00", "01/01/2020 20:10", "01/01/2020 20:22", ..., "01/01/2020 23:59", "01/02/2020 00:01", "01/02/2020 00:15", "01/02/2020 08:00", "01/02/2020 08:03", "01/02/2020 08:15")
```

And from this example I would like to obtain 2 blocks (in reality I would like to expect more blocks when I take in consideration more days, but in this case there are only 2 different days) :

```
block1 = c("01/01/2020 20:00", "01/01/2020 20:10", "01/01/2020 20:22", ..., "01/01/2020 23:59", "01/02/2020 00:01", "01/02/2020 00:15")

block2 = c("01/02/2020 08:00", "01/02/2020 08:03", "01/02/2020 08:15")
```

Comment: can you show a small reproduciible example and expected ouptut

Comment: @akrun, thanks for the observation. I forgot to include a toy example of what I would like to expect

Comment: I think `rleid` will be your friend

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will need to specify when to begin a new block of purchases. My suggestion is to define *the length of the gap* between two subsequent purchases to start a new block.

This can be accomplished using `data.table` for instance by

```
library(data.table)
# create sample data (as posted by the OP)
DT <- data.table(purchase.dates = c(
  "01/01/2020 20:00",
  "01/01/2020 20:10",
  "01/01/2020 20:22",
  "01/01/2020 23:59",
  "01/02/2020 00:01",
  "01/02/2020 00:15",
  "01/02/2020 08:00",
  "01/02/2020 08:03",
  "01/02/2020 08:15"))
# coerce to numeric date time
DT[, purchase.dates := lubridate::mdy_hm(purchase.dates)] 

# define length of gap between blocks (in minutes)
min_gap = 6*60
DT[, .(block.start = min(purchase.dates), block.end = max(purchase.dates)),
   by = .(block_id = cumsum(c(TRUE, as.numeric(diff(purchase.dates), units = "mins") >= min_gap)))]
```

which returns the expected two blocks

> ```
>    block_id         block.start           block.end
> 1:        1 2020-01-01 20:00:00 2020-01-02 00:15:00
> 2:        2 2020-01-02 08:00:00 2020-01-02 08:15:00
> ```

Now, you can vary `min_gap` to find out what is most suitable for your underlying problem.

E.g., with `min_gap <- 120` you will get 3 blocks:

```
   block_id         block.start           block.end
1:        1 2020-01-01 20:00:00 2020-01-01 20:22:00
2:        2 2020-01-01 23:59:00 2020-01-02 00:15:00
3:        3 2020-01-02 08:00:00 2020-01-02 08:15:00
```

because there were no purchases between 20:22 and 23:59.